# word boundaries preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, word-boundary

I would like to catch any piece of string that matches %[a-z0-9], respecting the following examples :

```
1. %xxxxxxxxxxxxx                                 //match
2. this will work %xxxxxx but not this%xxxxxxxxx. //match 1st, not 2nd
3. and also %xxxxxxxxxx.                          //match
4. just a line ending with %xxxxxxxxxxx           //match
5. %Xxxxxxxxxxx                                   //no match
6. 100% of dogs                                   //no match
7. 65%. Begining of new phrase                    //no match
8. 65%.Begining of new phrase                     //no match
```

It can be at the begining of the string or at the end, but not in the middle of a word. It can of course be in the string as a word (separated by space).

I have tried

```
/(\b)%[a-z0-9]+(\b)/
/(^|\b)%[a-z0-9]+($|\b)/
/(\w)%[a-z0-9]+(\w)/
```

and others like this, but I can't get it to work like I would. I guess the \b token does not work in example 2 because there is a boundary before the % sign.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
/\B%[a-z0-9]+\b/
```

You don't have a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` between a space and the `%`, but you have one between `s` and `%`.

`\B` is the opposite of `\b` not a word boundary.

See it here on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sW6eI8/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
%[a-z0-9]+(?=\s|$)|(?:^|(?<=\s))%[a-z0-9]+
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/20

```
$re = "/%[a-z0-9]+(?=\\s|$)|(?:^|(?<=\\s))%[a-z0-9]+/m";
$str = "1. %xxxxxxxxxxxxx //match\n2. this will work %xxxxxx but not this%xxxxxxxxx. //match 1st, not 2nd\n3. and also %xxxxxxxxxx. //match\n4. just a line ending with %xxxxxxxxxxx //match\n5. %Xxxxxxxxxxx //no match\n6. 100% of dogs //no match\n7. 65%. Begining of new phrase //no match\n8. 65%.Begining of new phrase //no match";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

or

```
%[a-z0-9]+\b|\b%[a-z0-9]+
```